# Native JS fetch API complete error handling. How?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've put together the following code from learning about the fetch API. I am trying to replace AJAX and this looks wonderful so far.

Main Question:

According to the [Fetch API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)...

> A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is
>   encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server side, although this
>   usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute
>   a network error, for example.

Having the 3 technologies working together...

If I **disable the Web Server** I get:

```
NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

**Wonderful. That works great.**

If I **disable MySQL** I get my custom error from PHP:

```
MySQL server down?
```

**Wonderful. That works great.**

If I **disable PHP** I get exactly nothing because the only way I can think of to pass through the Web Server request and trigger an error at the PHP level is **with a... timeout**.

After some research, I don't think there is a timeout option... at least not yet.

How could I implement it in the code below?

```js
// CLICK EVENT
$( "#btn_test" ).on('click', function() {
// Call function
test1();

});

function test1() {

// json() - Returns a promise that resolves with a JSON object.
function json_response(response) {  

// Check if response was ok.
if(response.ok) {
return response.json()
}

}

// data - Access JSON data & process it.
function json_response_data(data) {  
  console.log('json_response_data: ', data);
}

// URL to post request to...
var url = 'data_get_json_select_distinct_client.php';

// Sample serializeArray() from html form data.
// <input type="text" name="CLIENT_ID" value="1000">
var post_data = [{
"name":"CLIENT_ID",
"value":"1000"
}];

// STRINGIFY
post_data = JSON.stringify(post_data);

// FETCH
fetch(url, {  
method:   'post',  
headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}),  
body:      post_data 
})
// VALID JSON FROM SERVER?
.then(json_response)
// ACCESS JSON DATA.
.then(json_response_data)
// ERROR.
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Web server down?: ', error.message);
});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btn_test">FETCH RECORD</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server should be returning some sort of `5xx` error code, should there be a problem server-side.  This error is catchable in your JS.

Comment: I am literally testing it by leaving server online and turning off PHP. Since PHP is what fails next, I then press the button and while in AJAX I can handle this with a `timeout: 5000,`, in fetch API it does not seem to exist as an option.

Comment: @ASPiRE Your server should be immediately responding with some sort of 500 error.  This is a problem for your web server to deal with, and then return the proper error code for the client.  Do not set timeouts on the client like that, there are people with slower connections who you are breaking.

Comment: Argh! "slower connections"... right! I... over looked them. So, you're saying the request is sent to the server, the server somehow checks if php is online. If it is not, return response to client? Just to wrap my mind around your suggestion?

Comment: @ASPiRE Yes, sort of.  You didn't mention what server you're using, or what PHP API it's using, but this sort of thing is usually immediate.  You also didn't specify *how* you're disabling PHP.  let's assume PHP-FPM under Nginx over a socket, running locally on the same machine as the web server.  If that were the case, the web server should/would know immediately if it couldn't connect to PHP, and would immediately return a `500 Internal Server Error` to your client.

Comment: NGINX local but Apache in production.

Comment: @ASPiRE I'd fix that before trying to over-optimize your failure conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! On to research.